# regular expression in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My value is coming like this

```
"aaaa=7%2C778.00&bbbb=1%2C111%2C231.00"
```

I need

```
"aaaa"="7,778.00","bbbb"="1,111,231.00"
```

I wrote

```
addInsurance.replace(/([^&]+)=([^&]*)/g,function (match, name, addInsurance) {
     arrayOfInsurance[name] = addInsurance;
});
```

I got

```
"aaaa"="7%2C78.00","bbbb"="1%2C11%2C23.00"
```

how i can remove "%2C" by regex in jquery!! kindly help!!!!

Comment: You can simply use `decodeURI` of your url, then you can simply remove `,` :D

Comment: This looks like a query string and URL encoded data. Are you getting that from the URL? If so, there are better ways to do it than regex

Comment: There's no need for Regex here. Use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the value then `replace('&', ',')` to swap the `&` for a `,`

Comment: I was not aware of this... thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```js
var str = "vatInInsurance=7%2C778.00&totalPremiumInInsurance=1%2C111%2C231.00";

var str_decoded = decodeURIComponent(str).split('&').join();

console.log(str_decoded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use decodeURIComponent function to decode the value and then replace the & with comma.

Here is the sample code

```
var str = "vatInInsurance=7%2C778.00&totalPremiumInInsurance=1%2C111%2C231.00";
var resultString = decodeURIComponent(str).replace('&', ',');
```

Comment: & i removed.. i have a problem to remove both together(& and %2C)

Comment: ('$',' ') and ('%2C',',')

Comment: @mammam $2C will not be there after you execute decodeURIComponent function on the string